# Is it possible for PHPStorm to follow Magento syntax module/template declaration in XML files?

Tags: phpstorm

Simple questions. Is it possible for PHPStorm to follow Magento syntax module/template declaration in XML files? If yes, how would I achieve that?

```
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="Magento_Wishlist::rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
```

I would like to CTRL + Click on `Magento_Wishlist::rss/wishlist.phtml` part. And end up opening according file: `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/rss/wishlist.phtml`.

Support for custom modules would also be great!

EDIT: since it seems possible, any more alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

There is an official plugin for PHPStorm - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8024-magento-phpstorm
It should help

P.S. It's required to enable plugin in settings
[image]